# Problem with XML and XML-Schema cardinality

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML and XML-Schema. The XML contains filters and it is possible to include filters in another filter. Now I tried to use key and keyref in the schema but I get the error `The cardinality of the fields in keyref 'FilterKeyRef' must be equal to the cardinality of the identity constraint definition 'FilterIdKey'. The cardinality must be '1'`. I tried using several online tools, AI as well as colleagues but I still did not manage to solve the error. Does someone know how to resolve the issue?

Here is the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Filters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="example.xsd">
    <Filter>
        <Id>0</Id>
        <DisplayName>Filter1</DisplayName>
    </Filter>
    <Filter>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <DisplayName>Filter2</DisplayName>
    </Filter>
    <Filter>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <DisplayName>Filter3</DisplayName>
        <FiltersToInclude>
            <FilterToInclude>
                <Id>0</Id>
                <DisplayName>Filter1</DisplayName>
            </FilterToInclude>
            <FilterToInclude>
                <Id>1</Id>
                <DisplayName>Filter2</DisplayName>
            </FilterToInclude>
        </FiltersToInclude>
    </Filter>
</Filters>
```

Here is the XML-Schema:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <xs:element name="DisplayName" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>    
        
        <xs:element name="Filter">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="Id" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element ref="DisplayName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element ref="FiltersToInclude" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        
        <xs:element name="FilterToInclude">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="Id" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element ref="DisplayName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        
        <xs:element name="FiltersToInclude">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="FilterToInclude" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>       
        
        <xs:element name="Filters">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="Filter" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:key name="FilterIdKey">
                <xs:selector xpath="Filter/Id"></xs:selector>
                <xs:field xpath="."></xs:field>
            </xs:key>
            <xs:key name="FilterDisplayNameKey">
                <xs:selector xpath="Filter/DisplayName"></xs:selector>
                <xs:field xpath="."></xs:field>
            </xs:key>
            <xs:keyref name="FilterKeyRef" refer="FilterIdKey">
                <xs:selector xpath="Filter/FiltersToInclude/FilterToInclude"></xs:selector>
                <xs:field xpath="./Id"></xs:field>
                <xs:field xpath="./DisplayName"></xs:field>
            </xs:keyref>
        </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Do you want the key for `Filter` to be composed by `Id` and `DisplayName`? Then use e.g. `<xs:key name="FilterKey"><xs:selector xpath="Filter"/><xs:field xpath="Id"/><xs:field xpath="DisplayName"/></xs:key>` and then `refer="FilterKey` for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of Martin Honnen I managed to get it right.

Here is the new XML-Schema:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- W3C Schema generated by XMLSpy v2021 rel. 3 (x64) (http://www.altova.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <!--     simple elements -->
        <xs:element name="DisplayName" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>    
        
        <xs:element name="Filter">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="Id" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element ref="DisplayName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element ref="FiltersToInclude" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        
        <xs:element name="FilterToInclude">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="Id" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element ref="DisplayName" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        
        <xs:element name="FiltersToInclude">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="FilterToInclude" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>       
        
        <xs:element name="Filters">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="Filter" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:key name="FilterKey">
                <xs:selector xpath="Filter"></xs:selector>
                <xs:field xpath="Id"></xs:field>
                <xs:field xpath="DisplayName"></xs:field>
            </xs:key>
            <xs:keyref name="FilterKeyRef" refer="FilterKey">
                <xs:selector xpath="Filter/FiltersToInclude/FilterToInclude"></xs:selector>
                <xs:field xpath="./Id"></xs:field>
                <xs:field xpath="./DisplayName"></xs:field>
            </xs:keyref>
        </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```